# Inserting correctly area to MySQL database and getting back

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html, textarea

I have form in html (php). This form includes text area which is used to save log from swich, router, etc. to database. 
Command line of terminal usualy have 80 cols(bytes on line) so i set the atribute cols to 80.

```
<tr>
  <td><label for="taskText">Text:</label> </td>
  <td><textarea name="taskText" id="taskText" cols="80" rows="10" required></textarea></td> 
</tr>
```

**Motivation**: Why I do this? I have table in database which have this colums id (INT-autoincrement),log1(TEXT), log2(TEXT).

User save two logs into database, then I get them from database and save log1 to field $log1 and log2 to the field $log2, where $log1 will be array, where the keys will be lines.

for example:
`

```
$log1[0]="line1";
$log1[1]="line2";
$log1[2]="line3";`
```

**Problem:** So the problem is copy text of log to the textarea, then save it properly to the database(MYSQL) to the field of type TEXT(I choosed this hope well) and have preserved the end of lines (somehow), then load the log from the database to array, where each key will be one line (like in example now without the mark for end of line).

**My solution**: 
Using function nl2br before saving to the database and durring loading from database use function explode:

```
$log1=explode("<br />", $stringWithLogLoadedFromDatabase);
```

But I'm not sure if this is good solution. Any other ideas?

**NOTE:**
I wrote there some background of my solution, but the main problem is only with end of lines of input text(log) which I´ll copy to the text area and save to the database. So I need to now where are original end of lines to be able to work with the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the following,

Use `htmlspecialchars()` on the string to put into the DB, and then, when pulling it back out, use `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

These two might make a output as per you query.

Comment: But I thought this doesn´t solve the problem with recognising the end of lines. To know where the end of lines are and be able to save it to the aray then. Or maybe I does´t see the point.